# Multiple conditions for while loop

Tags: python

I'm writing a function that checks if a checkers piece can do jump moves, and stop when it can't jump, so I wrote:

```
def checkJump(x,y,count,incr):
player = board[x][y]
count = 0

jumpleft = (board[x+incr][y+incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y+incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y+(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y+(incr*2) <= 7

jumpright = (board[x+incr][y-incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y-incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y-(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y-(incr*2) <= 7

while jumpleft or jumpright:    
    while jumpleft:
        x += incr*2
        y += incr*2
        count += 1
        jumpleft = (board[x+incr][y+incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y+incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y+(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y+(incr*2) <= 7

    while jumpright:
        x += incr*2
        y -= incr*2
        count += 1
        jumpright = (board[x+incr][y-incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y-incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y-(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y-(incr*2) <= 7

    jumpleft = (board[x+incr][y+incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y+incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y+(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y+(incr*2) <= 7

    jumpright = (board[x+incr][y-incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y-incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y-(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y-(incr*2) <= 7
return x,y,count
```

However, the conditions for checking is too redundant, multiple conditions are connected with `and` . Is there a better way to write multiple conditions for a while loop instead just chaining them with `and`? Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: Are you expecting the while loops to perform animation?

Comment: `while` never had same level 2(two) conditions. While func required **unique timing elements** (not value, timing). How to handle when user press 2 keys on same time ?(bad boy, don't do  it !). so use `if jumpleft : ..... elif jumpright`(don't use `else`). And never calculate a value if condution not excepted. And divide CPU clock with external triger. Mean don't waste CPU if haven't any action. Maybe your code `awesome` but you need a `break` every sub loop(terrible idea, how to scan which break excepted ? Print something on RTC ap ? :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define two checking functions which return True or False:

```
def jumpleft(x, y, board, incr):
    return (board[x+incr][y+incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y+incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y+(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y+(incr*2) <= 7

def jumpright(x, y, board, incr):
    return (board[x+incr][y-incr] != player) and (board[x+incr][y-incr] != '') and (board[x+(incr*2)][y-(incr*2)] == '') and 0 <= x <= 7 and 0 <= y <= 7 and 0 and 0 <= x+incr <= 7 and 0 <= x+(incr*2) <= 7 and 0 <= y-(incr*2) <= 7
```

And just call them to get the values. That would make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in game programming, i'd recommend pygame. If you're not interested, i'd recommend replacing a number of the "and" assignment operators with conditional "if statements". They serve the same purpose and are more readable.